# Was Boba Fett implanted with the inhibitor/control chip?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, boba-fett

When Jango Fett was hired to donate his DNA for the creation of the Clone Army he was paid considerably and had made a request for the creation of a clone to himself which didn't have the Genetic modifications, such as behavioural conditioning and growth acceleration.

That clone's name was Boba Fett and like all other clones he was a cloned Embryo and every Embryo was implanted with the inhibitor chip after the third embryonic stage, does this mean that Boba Fett had an inhibitor chip or did Jango Fett also requested that the clone (Boba Fett) wouldn't be implanted with the chip?

Answer (score 11):

Boba Fett did not undergo the same accelerated growth process as the other clones but was allowed to develop naturally

```
          LAMA SU           
     Apart from his pay, 
     which is considerable,
     Fett demanded only one thing - 
     an unaltered clone for himself. 
     Curious isn't it?
```

[Episode II  - Attack of the Clones](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html) script

Additionally, though not strictly canon - [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boba_Fett) has this note for Boba Fett and cites the source as Episode II:

> Jango agreed to become the genetic template for a considerable
>   payment, as well as one request: the creation of a clone who did not
>   have the same genetic modifications, such as behavioral conditioning
>   and growth acceleration.

Comment: This does say that he wasn't implanted with the chip

Comment: what does "unaltered" mean to you? :)

Comment: Well I mean, I'd consider him being unaltered even if he had the chip implanted, personally

Comment: I think it is fairly clear that the implication is that Boba is specifically not the same as the trooper clones and that this was Jango's intention.

Comment: That's no the point I'm arguing, but I'm merely one in a crowd of people. And the community has clearer decided for me, as it should be

Comment: no worries friend!

Comment: ^_^ "unaltered" is also amusing to me because that's used by veterinarians to refer to pets that haven't been neutered or spayed...